# Rectangle doesnt change its position when "SizeChanged" Event gets activated

Tags: c#, wpf, rectangles

I have a [window with rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Mun.png) in it and when I make my window bigger by dragging [it to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8rVZ.png) the rectangles are also following and staying in the middle, but when I [drag the window down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfOqD.png) it does nothing.

This is my code where I create the rectangles:

```
        Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)_random.Next(1, 255), (byte)_random.Next(1, 255), (byte)_random.Next(1, 255)));
        Rectangle[] MyRectangle = new Rectangle[howmanyrect];
        SizeChanged += (sender, args) => ChangeRectangleSize(MyRectangle, rectangleHeight, howmanyrect, distancebetweenrectangles);

        for (int i = 0; i < howmanyrect; i++)
        {
            var rectangle = new Rectangle
            {
                Fill = brush,
                StrokeThickness = strokethickness,
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                Width = rectangleWidth,
                Height = rectangleHeight / howmanyrect - distancebetweenrectangles
            };
            MyRectangle[i] = rectangle;

            Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, Width / 2.0 - rectangle.Width / 2.0);
            Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, distancefirstrectotop + i * (rectangleHeight / howmanyrect) + distancebetweenrectangles);

            myCanvas.Children.Add(rectangle);
            Content = myCanvas;
        }
```

And this is my code for the method that should make the rectangle stay in the middle:

```
    public void ChangeRectangleSize(Rectangle[] recobject, int recheight, int numberrecs, int recdistance)
    {          
        for (int i = 0; i < recobject.Length; i++)
        {              
            Canvas.SetLeft(recobject[i], Width / 2.0 - recobject[i].Width / 2.0);
            Canvas.SetTop(recobject[i], 30 + i * (recheight / numberrecs) + recdistance);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you call `Canvas.SetTop` you don't use the `Height` property of the window so it will never move any further down.

Comment: @DavidG i did this now: Canvas.SetTop(recobject[i], Height / 2.0 - recobject[i].Height / 2.0); but now there is only 1 rectangle and the others are not there anymore

Comment: Well, now you're not factoring in the current `i` in the calculation. Note you can do all this maths on a sheet of paper. Do that and you should be able to figure out the actual calculation.